# Which of the ESP8266 alternatives allows for full packet capture/injection in promiscuous mode?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, wifi

I am part of a product group that is developing a low cost wireless intrusion detection system, for home usage.

We have already produced and delivered to market ESP8266 based product however for the new thing, we need the chipset to be able to enter promiscuous mode and receive/inject 802.11 packets on the fly without any limits.

ESP8266 is limited to 112bytes max, which is not enough to even parse the Beacon frame properly.

What are the alternatives for ESP8266 currently - that allow:

- to capture the 802.11 frames
- have no packet length limits
- allow packet injection

Ps. doesn't have to be ARDUINO - but needs to be C/C++ programmable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using encryption on your WiFi network?

Comment: Obviously, people do use encryption WEP(rarely)/WPA/2. Why do you ask ?

Comment: Because if you have encryption there is no such thing as promiscuous mode. You can't see anyone elses frames, they are encrypted. You want raw radio data access, and that then means manually decrypting packets to make any sense of anything.

Comment: Well you can still have promisc enabled and receive DATA packets that are encrypted. You can decrypt them later on if you know the key, not sure what's your point. Simply put, ESP does the job, but is limited with 112bytes which is not enough to perform full packet analysis.

Comment: That sounds more like direct radio data access than promiscuous mode.  If the ESP8266 can do it (kind of) then the ESP32 can most likely do it far better.

Comment: Unfortunately both 32 and 8266 have a limit set by ESPRESSIF for max length of a packet to 112 bytes. What does it mean? You get a MGMT Beacon frame length 239 bytes. All you can read is first 112 bytes, while in the rest of it you get trash...

Comment: Maybe something like the CC3100MOD would do the job. Not sure about programming it, but it has an ARM CPU embedded in it, so you can certainly use GCC. There's probably some toolkit available from TI from it. I've never used one, so I can't comment.